# How can I call a function defined inside a module of requirejs from my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, requirejs

In my server page I have:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<script src="../../Scripts/libs/require.js" data-main="../../Scripts/main.js"></script>

<asp:GridView>
    ...
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton
                    ID="lb" runat="server" 
                    OnClientClick='<%# string.Format("return onButtonClick({0});", Eval("ProviderId") %>'
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        ...
    </Columns>
<asp:GridView>
```

And my main.js looks like:

```
    require.config({
        baseUrl: "../../Scripts",
        ...
    });

    require(function () {
        function onButtonClick(providerId) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

The function defined inside main.js is not visible in the server side, i.e., the OnClientClick button handler. Moreover, I need to pass the "ProviderId" data bound field as a function argument.

Any ideas on how can I make this function visible to the aspx code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite experienced in ASP, but can assume, that exporting function to global scope might do the trick. I would try something like this:

```
 require.config({
     baseUrl: "../../Scripts",
        ...
 });

 require(function () {
     function onButtonClick(providerId) {
         ...
     }
     window.onButtonClick = onButtonClick
 });
```

Don'y know if this is important, but:
It will take some time even after domReady event for requirejs to load all modules, so, in theory, the function may be not defined just yet. Using of [requirejs optimizer](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/) would allow to bypass this problem.

Comment: Yes, that way will do the trick, its actually a more elegant solution what I was looking for. Sounds like I'm missing something here, maybe requirejs enforces a different approach when manipulating DOM objects than just exporting functions to a global scope.